# Scaling limit of ODE with double-well potential

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let us consider the ODE
$$
\frac{d}{dt}x_\epsilon(t) = -\frac{1}{\epsilon} W'(x_\epsilon(t))
$$
where $W$ is a double-well potential -- for example, $W(x)=\frac{1}{4}(x^2-1)^2$ so that the ODE reads
$$
\frac{d}{dt}x_\epsilon(t) = \frac{1}{\epsilon} x_\epsilon(t)\big(1-x_\epsilon(t)^2\big).
$$

Can the limit of $x_\epsilon$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ be characterized?

Comment: This is just a rescaling of time in the standard double well ODE, and the time rescaled solution will converge to either $\{0, \pm 1\}$ depending on the initial condition.  Having said that, I think MSE would be a better fit for this question.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Do you have a reference for the result?

Comment: By the chain rule, note that $x_{\epsilon}(t) = x_1(t/\epsilon)$ and the asymptotic behavior of $x_1$ is discussed in most undergraduate elementary differential equations book.  Hope that helps.